# Cordova 3.6 exit app not working properly. Bug?

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova

Very strange behavior when calling

```
navigator.app.exitApp();
```

on Cordova 3.6

The home screen shows, application continues to run in background and **Admob ads are displayed over the home screen**.
When running the app again, a new instance runs even tough

```
<preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTask" />
```

is set in the config.xml, which normally makes it run in single task. 
Any suggestions?